# Question about Grover algorithm implementation in the Quirk simulator

Tags: quantum-gate, grovers-algorithm, quirk

I want to implement the Grover iteration instead of the multi-control qubit implemented as in this picture:

[image]

I want to implement them like in this example of five qubits:
[image]

I mean how can I decompose them in the circuit (picture1)?

[This is my attempt](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,1,1,1,%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,1,1,%22H%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,1,1,%22H%22],[%22Chance6%22]],%22gates%22:[%7B%22id%22:%22~akt%22,%22name%22:%22Oracle%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:[[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22]]%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~pb2i%22,%22name%22:%22Amplif%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,1,1,%22H%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,1,1,%22H%22]]%7D%7D]%7D) but I failed to get the amplitude increases for the state |1111> (after measuring the wires 1,2,3 and 6)

If you could do it in the Quirk simulator, that will be too helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're struggling with. What's stopping you from just taking the second picture and creating it in Quirk?

Comment: Actually I did but I don't get the same chance of finding the state |1111>.
I don't know where I'm wrong in my implementation.

Comment: Well in the second picture there are 5 control qubits whereas in the first there are 4. Maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Yes I know but this not the problem, the seconde picture is just an example on how I want the multi control for 4 qubits and 3 qubits in the first picture to look like, I mean to decompose them in an approprite way.

Comment: Hi @Craig Gidney pls see the edited question, I added a link to my attempt if you could figure out my error :). And thank you.

Comment: The second half of the circuit is wrong. Your decomposition of the CCCCNOT looks like a CCCNOT decomposition, and also the ancillae it is using are from your state instead of zero'd qubits.

Comment: The second multi-qubits control (half of the circuit) is indeed a CCCNOT as shown in picture 1. Do I need to use other ancillary qubits for this CCCNOT?

Comment: The second half should look basically identical to the first half.

Comment: How is that? I mean the first half is a CCCCNOT gate (6CCNOT+1CNOT)  and the second half is a CCCNOT gate (4CCNOT+1CNOT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second half of the circuit you're mixing up which qubits are your ancillae and which are the ones you want to operate on. You can't use one of your system qubits as an ancilla.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That was clear. Thank you so much.